# I cannot connect to remote postgres database

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, networking, telnet

netstat gives:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32707/postgres
```

"postgresql.conf" reads:

```
listen_addresses = "*"
```

"pg_hba.conf" reads:

```
host    all             all             xx.xx.xx.xx/0         trust
```

where xx.xx.xx.xx is my host address

Ruling out the firewall, ufw status shows:

```
5432                       ALLOW       xx.xx.xx.xx
```

After restarting the postgres service I try:

```
psql -h yy.yy.yy.yy -p 5432
```

The connection hangs and then times out.  I can connect fine via SSH but oddly, telnet hangs as well.  I also cannot connect to the database from a local network computer.

Comment: The local (to the server) ufw is not the only firewall involved for a from-remote connection.

Comment: A network or firewall problem.

Comment: UFW is supposed to be allowing connections of 5432 As I have the rule set.  Netstat is saying: 5432/tcp closed postgresql, even when I disable the firewall.  What other firewall is involved jjanes?  I've also disabled my router firewall and nothing has changed.  I'm having the same problem on the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

The crucial command was:

```
sudo systemctl status 'postgresql*'
```

This let me know that the psql service was not running and gave me a verbose reason why (permission conflict with and IP).  Secondly, gateway port forwarding needs to be allowing 5432/TCP.